# UI-Router Child/nested state does not load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've had a look at similar questions, but their problem seems to resolve around the lack of `<ui-view />` tag in the parent HTML. Here, it's not the case.

I have a child state that does not load:

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('myapp').config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

//A bunch of unrelated routes

$stateProvider.state({
        'name': 'users',
        'url': '/users',
        'controller': 'usersCtrl',
        'templateUrl': '/scripts/pages/users/users.html'
    });

$stateProvider.state({
    'name': 'users.editeduser',
    'url': '/editeduser',
    'template': '<h1>HELLO</h1>'
    // 'templateUrl': '/scripts/pages/users/parts/editedUser.html',
    // 'controller': 'editedUserCtrl'
    // 'resolve':  {
    //     editedUserId: function(editedUserId) {
    //         return editedUserId;
    //     }
    // }
});
```

**users.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Users List</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">{{user.firstname + " " + user.lastname}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ui-view name="users.editeduser"></ui-view>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="user-edit">New User</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the html code `uiview` line, I tried using `<ui-view name=".editeduser"></ui-view>` and I also tried just `<ui-view name="editeduser"></ui-view>` to no avail. I even tried `<div ui-view=...`.

As you can see in the commented out routes.js code, there is a supposed controller and html template that the child is supposed to have, but I removed them for the sake of trying to work out the problem.

In Chrome Dev Tools, this is the output:
[image: Image showing Chrome Dev tools view of page]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: create a fiddle/plunker from your code to get it solved faster

Answer (score 1):

The `ui-sref` for the button doesn't match the url for that state:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <!-- ERRONEOUS 
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="user-edit">New User</button>
    -->
    <!-- INSTEAD -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="users/editeduser">New User</button>
</div>
```

---

> I think you're onto something though because at no where to I call the child state in my code, and I think I need to call it for it to be loaded, but I am not sure of how to. I'll try to look at the documentation and see –

The [UI-Router for AngularJS (1.x) - Hello Galaxy! Tutorial](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellogalaxy) has a DEMO that shows a state with a list of people. The child view with information on an individual only becomes visible when the person is selected.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/cJLkUsiGMby0TWQZ1A0Q?p=preview)

Comment: As confusing as it sounds, there is another state called "user-edit" `$stateProvider.state({
        'name': 'user-edit',
        'url': '/user-edit',
        'controller': 'userEditCtrl',
        'templateUrl': '/scripts/pages/users/userEdit.html'
    });`

Comment: I think you're onto something though because at no where to I call the child state in my code, and I think I need to call it for it to be loaded, but I am not sure of how to. I'll try to look at the documentation and see

Comment: I tested it. That was the problem!